# Macbook Pro A1502 Help Needed

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake, charging

Earlier post was deleted as it sound similar to other posted question, I did check and its not the same problem.

I have problem with MacBook Pro Retina A1502, I believe the battery is drained while on Sleep Mode and since then it cant turn on or charge. I did tried  resetting the SMC, the indicator turn Green for awhile and back to Orange (on charging indicator). Wait for awhile a press the Power Button, still not powering up. I need to fix this, I do use this MacBook for work and cant afford a new one and I cant decide what to fix since,

1. Charger cable has one minor cut but it's still working even sometime it turn off if misposition
2. Battery drain normal for an old unit, still okay for around 30-45 minutes. But it was drained while on Sleep Mode and happen like twice earlier but can turn on while charging before the current state happened and its now refused to power up or charging.

I need some help, please do advise;

**a**. Is it true Macbook wont turn on (with charger only) if the battery is dead?
**b**. Should I just buy a charger replacement first to confirm this is charger problem?
**c**. Should I just replace the battery?
**d**. Something else is bad (e.g DC Pwr Jack Board)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you were only getting 30-45 minutes of use out of the battery then it is most likely the culprit.  The battery is probably acting like a drain and preventing your system from booting.  I'd look at that before buying a new charger.